# Concatenate SQL columns with comma separated

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string-aggregation, stuff

Is there any alternate way to concatenate SQL columns with comma separated. I am using below logic for concatenation. The columns (col1,col2,col3) can have **null** values.

```
select 
stuff(
        left(concat(col1,',',col2,',',col3),
            len(concat(col1,',',col2,',',col3)) -
        patindex('%[^,]%',reverse(concat(col1,',',col2,',',col3)))+1
            )
        ,1,
        patindex('%[^,]%',concat(col1,',',col2,',',col3))-1,''
    )
from mytable
```

- Sample data/output

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: For a fixed number of columns you can use `case ` and `+`.

Comment: Seems like you'd do MUCH better letting the client code handling this, rather than doing this work on a server where the licensing costs are often as much as $7K/core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `concat` separators conditionally. This will output an empty string if either of the columns are null or empty.

```
select concat(col1,
              case when len(col2)>1 then ',' else '' end,
              col2,
              case when len(col3)>1 then ',' else '' end,
              col3) 
from your_table;
```

To output null if either of the columns are null or empty, wrap the `concat` inside a `nullif` like this

```
select nullif(concat(col1,
              case when len(col2)>1 then ',' else '' end,
              col2,
              case when len(col3)>1 then ',' else '' end,
              col3),'')
from your_table;
```

Answer (score 5):

In more recent versions of SQL Server you can use [`concat_ws()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select concat_ws(',', col1, col2, col3)
```

In earlier versions, there are various approach.  A pretty simple one is:

```
select stuff( concat(',' + col1, ',' + col2, ',' + col3), 1, 1, '')
```

Comment: concat_ws - I am using SQL server 2014, so it wont work.

Comment: select stuff( concat(',' + col1, ',' + col2, ',' + col3), 1, 1, '') - This is good, works for column having NULL's. what if the data is empty string?

Comment: @MRR . . . Then you will get two commas in a row.

Comment: @MRR, if you have any idea how to concatenate removing the trailing spaces of individual columns